# Индекс элемента в IQueryable

Tags: c#, linq, orm

Доброго времени суток, собственно сабж в заголовке.
Пробовал юзать метод ToList(), но... но метод Contains у интерфейса возвращает true, а у получившегося List - false.

более подробно алгоритм:
заюзал ORM для MSSQL, создаю элемент таблицы Log:

```
SQL.DeviceDataBase db = new SQL.DeviceDataBase(
  @"Data Source=" + Core.Settings.SQL_ServerName + @";
  Initial Catalog=" + Core.Settings.SQL_DeviceBaseName + @";
  Integrated Security=True");

var log = new SQL.Log();
log.Date = _time;
log.ArriveDate = _now;
log.DeviceID = _device;
log.ChannelID = channel;
log.UserID = user;
log.Message = _message;
log.Type = _type.ToString();
log.Hash = _hash;

db.Logs.InsertOnSubmit(log);
db.SubmitChanges();
return log;
```

далее получаю общий список текущих отображаемых Log:

```
SQL.DeviceDataBase db = new SQL.DeviceDataBase(
  @"Data Source=" + Core.Settings.SQL_ServerName + @";
  Initial Catalog=" + Core.Settings.SQL_DeviceBaseName + @";
  Integrated Security=True");

IQueryable<Log> logs =
    from lgs in db.Logs
    where (
        lgs.Date >= _date &&
        (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_device) || lgs.DeviceID == null || lgs.DeviceID.Contains(_device)) &&
        lgs.Message.Contains(_message) &&
        lgs.Type.Contains(_type))
    select lgs;

return logs.OrderBy(order, ascending).Take(Core.Settings.LogMaximumCount);
```

в результате получаю код вида:

```
SQL.Log item = SQL.SQLCommander.CreateLogItem(_time, _device, _channel, _user, _message, _type);
IQueryable<SQL.Log> items = GetItems(starttime, SDevice, SMessage, SType, TOrder, BEnd);
```

а потом необходимо добавить item в GUI. Я покумекал, постоянно перерисовывать все данные жутко, и хотелось бы просто добавить в таблицу (на самом деле без биндинга, просто StackPanel с толпой UserControl'ов) одну единственную строку, но опять таки, может быть много различных фильтров, сортировок и пр., по этому хотел узнать индекс добавляемого итема, и по этому же индексу произвести Insert в StackPanel. Но нихрена чтото так не работает:

```
bool c = items.Contains(item);                      //true
bool d = items.ToList<SQL.Log>().Contains(item);    //false
bool e = items.ToArray<SQL.Log>().Contains(item);   //false
```

а метод IndexOf есть только у List... в общем, у меня получилось сделать операцию только используя дикий костыль:

```
List<SQL.Log> lst= items.ToList<SQL.Log>();
SQL.Log item = lst.Where(x => x.ID == item.ID).FirstOrDefault();
index = lst.IndexOf(item1);
```

и у меня получилось это порядка 400 миллисекунд, хрень.
кто виноват разберёмся потом, но второй извечный вопрос остаётся, что делать?) может у кого какие идеи есть?

Comment: оу, забыл уточнить =) язык - C#, технология (если вдруг это важно) - WPF

Comment: А что за ORM Вы используете?

Comment: `SQL.Log` свой покажите. В общем случае две переменные ссылочного типа считаются равными, если они указывают на один и тот же объект. А то что ORM считает их равными - особенность этой ORM. Например при сравнении строк EntityFramework не учитывает регистр, а CLR учитывает, поэтому результаты могут отличаться. Определитесь что вы подразумеваете под равенством `SQL.Log` и проверяйте конкретно это условие (может по ID, например, надо сравнивать)

Comment: @Serafim Prozorov касательно ORM - обычный LinqToSql, генерируемый через SQLMetal (https://professorweb.ru/my/LINQ/linq_sql/level9/9_3.php) по этому примеру

Comment: @Андрей мой SQL.Log даже и не знаю как адекватно показать (ну недостаточно опытен я на этом сервисе)), длинна сообщения превышена на 14к символов. По ID сравнивать пробовал (через Where(=>)), но это оказалось медленно, если количество строк в выборке превышают хотя бы тысячу

Comment: @Spectral-Owl господи, зачем же Вы откопали труп-то... Предыдущий комментатор ответил Вам верно. Скорее всего ORM находит элемент, потому что с точки зрения SQL два объекта (записи) равны, если у них одинаковые первичные ключи, а для CLR -- если они равны по ссылке. Мне кажется, что Вы перемудрили, может быть стоит использовать грид и привязку данных? Тогда Вы сможете программировать, а не воевать с фреймворком.

Comment: @Spectral-Owl забыл сказать. Поиск перебором по списку, да еще и два раза (поиск элемента и поиск индекса) естественно будет медленным. Сложность линейного поиска -- O(n) и его не ускорить никак. Скажите, а Вы можете описать Ваше приложение: что оно делает, какой функционал, возможно, тогда Вам смогут что-то посоветовать.

Comment: @SerafimProzorov Диспетчеризация. Данный кусок - журнал событий (при этом сами события не текущего времени (принимаю данные со сторонних устройств с меткой времени, и по ним события генерирую). +При добавлении лезу в базу и чекаю валидность последнего события. +По разному отображаю разные типы событий. +Выборка и сортировка может быть какой угодно. При малых объёмах данных всё нормально, но когда общее количество начало превышать 20000, и при этом в секунду приходят штуки 3 новых (экстримальные условия тестирования), я просто не успеваю их все обработать (если искать индекс. Не ищя - всё ок).

Comment: @SerafimProzorov Это не смотря на то, что при выборке явно использовал Take(x), читал что он здорово экономит время выборки... хм... может это из-за того что я его после OrderBy использовал? Но поменять местами тоже нельзя, если порядок будет обратный, В этом же случае я могу хотеть посмотреть первую тысячу событий, а не последнюю тысячу событий, отсортированную в другом порядке.. хотя, механизм выборки за указанный интервал, а не просто последние за X времени, я предоставил, по идее можно и поменять местами Take и OrderBy. Наверное)